# Comparison between my day in table and the sysdate in server

Tags: function, plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to write function to return `day_id` after comparing current day name on the server and day name on my table contents

**my code is

```
 create or replace 
 FUNCTION GETSYSDATE
 return char 
 is
 v_day char(20) ;
 v_day_id days.day_id%type ;
 v_day_name days.day_name%type ;
 begin
 select day_id, to_char(sysdate, 'day', 'nls_date_language=arabic'), day_name
 into v_day_id,v_day,v_day_name
 from days
 where v_day_name = v_day ;
 return v_day_id ;
 end;
```

but Unfortunately,it's no data found !

note ! : the dataType of `day_name` is `varchar (20 byte)`

```
**the error
 Connecting to the database admin.
 ORA-01403: no data found
 ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.GETSYSDATE", line 9
 ORA-06512: at line 5
 Process exited.
 Disconnecting from the database admin.

** my table 
 DAY_ID NUMBER
 DAY_NAME   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is using local variables that have not been initialised; in fact you're trying to set them and use them to filter at the same time, which doesn't make much sense.

```
where v_day_name = v_day
```

... is never going to match any records from your table.

I think this does what you want:

```
create or replace function getsysdate return days.day_id%type is
  v_day_id days.day_id%type;
begin
  select day_id
  into v_day_id
  from days
  where day_name = to_char(sysdate, 'day', 'nls_date_language=arabic');
  return v_day_id;
end;
/
```

I don't know how your `days` table is populated, but I'm guessing the `day_id` is 1-7 and the `day_name` is the corresponding day, and that in your region you can't get that easily with a simple `TO_CHAR`. So [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e606/1) shows that function based on that assumption, but probably with the IDs in the wrong order. I've shown it both as an assignment in an anonymous block, and used from plain SQL.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, you have a table filled will days name and you want to query the equivalent day_id of server current date.
 
So there is multiple errors in the script like:
As you want the `GETSYSDATE` returning `DAY_ID`, you need to declare return statement as Number or  `DAYS.DAY_ID%TYPE` 
There is false condition on your `select` and `where` syntax.
...
May this function helps you

```
CREATE Function GETSYSDATE RETURN number
 is
 v_day_id days.DAY_ID%TYPE;
 begin
   select day_id
   into v_day_id
   from days
   where DAY_NAME = to_char(sysdate, 'day', 'nls_date_language=arabic') ;
   return v_day_id ;
   exception when no_data_found then
  return -1;
 end;
```

[Sqlfiddle show](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb95f/5).